# Author of books about Mexican guru

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying unsuccessfully to remember the name of American author who wrote a series of very popular books during the sixties or seventies on his encounter with a Mexican guru. Any suggestions?

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much. Exactly the answer I was seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be referring to [Carlos Castaneda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Castaneda), whose books on travelling through Mexico and psychedelic experiences, beginning with "The Teachings of Don Juan" were indeed very popular in the seventies.